# Apache Storm 1.1.0

Tags: apache-storm

I have a topology that has been created using Apache storm. I have created different Bolts and spout in place to perform various activities. However, I am planning on creating an automated test suite for testing the functionalities of the topology.

Can some help me if you have done a similar thing or suggest me a tool/language that helps me to achieve it? Currently, my topology is in Java.

Answer (score 2):

The fastests tests are going to be unit tests. If you can write most of your business logic in a way that is decoupled from Storm's APIs, you can write your tests as regular JUnit tests, maybe with Mockito or a similar tool to stub collaborators. Basically your standard Java unit tests.

For integration testing where you need to check whether you're using Storm correctly, or need to do a full end to end test of your topology, you can look at the `org.apache.storm.Testing` class, which helps you start a `LocalCluster`. There are some examples at https://github.com/xumingming/storm-lib/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/TestingApiDemo.java. The basic idea is to boot up Storm in the same JVM as the test, and then deploy the topology into it.

As of 2.0.0 there's a `LocalCluster` builder class making it a little easier to instantiate `LocalCluster` from Java.

Just to give an idea of what `LocalCluster` offers:

- Can run your topology in the same process as your tests
- You can enable *tuple tracking*, which causes the cluster to track all emitted tuples from all components. This lets you e.g. assert that a certain tuple was emitted from a certain component.
- Lets you replace your spouts with stubs. This can let you inject specific tuples into the topology easily, e.g. using a `FixedTupleSpout` or `FeederSpout`.
- Lets you do assertions about which tuples were acked/failed
- Some stubbed spouts are *completable spouts*, which means they have an API to indicate to Storm when they have emitted and acked/failed all tuples. This can let you e.g. start a topology in the test and ask for Storm to run it until all tuples are processed. This makes it easier to write tests that are not flaky, since you don't need to know how long it takes to finish processing your tuples.

For other examples of how to use `LocalCluster`, you can take a look at some of our own integration tests at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/8f49e06998abb4dfc50f51d78b6784ebd04844fb/storm-core/test/jvm/org/apache/storm/integration/TopologyIntegrationTest.java. Please ignore the way the topologies are wired in these tests, you should just use `TopologyBuilder` in your own tests.

Comment: Hi @Stig Rohde Døssing, Thanks. It is really helpful.